# setText method for UITextView only works from the second time since the method is called.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm having a problem with setText method for UITextView.

As I said on the title, I tried to change a UITextView text by using setText method or change the text property directly. It only works from the second time since the method is called.

My UITextView was an outlet. I even tried to change it's text directly from the owner class or create a method to call from another class, but it behaves the same.

I dont know if I'm doing sth wrong when create it as an outlet, I also tried to set it as nonatomic, strong, weak, retain but I still can't get it.

Any advice for my case? Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:
I figured it out from David H's answer.

As my app is using tab, first tab is used for searching words, the second one for displaying the meaning, I tried to set the text before the outlet is created (as I haven't clicked the second tab yet). If I click the tab meaning first in order to let the outlet to be created, then it works perfectly.

Thanks for all the answer!

Comment: Advice:  show your code.

Comment: Where are you trying to change it's text? init method? viewDidLoad? custom method? Using my mind reading powers (since you haven't shown your code), I'd guess that you're trying to call the setText method before the outlet was set.

Comment: Hi, I figured it out and edited. Anyway, your answer also helped me, I'll keep in mind if the method is called in init, didload or the custom one. Thanks a lots!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost for sure, the first time you try to set it the outlet is nil - not yet set. So add an assert (`assert(myTextView`) before you set it, or at least a NSLog message. You will surely find that the textView is nil the first time you try.